# Ionic on Ubuntu get java error when run "ionic emulate android" command

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, ionic-framework

I cannot run the "ionic emulate android" command.
I keep getting following error message:

[image]

I have already installed the java,
when I run "java -version", i got this

```
java version "1.7.0_95"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```

when I run "which java", I got this

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Is anyone, have an idea why am I getting this error?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed ANDROID_SDK properly and added `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` into your path? And then check whether your `hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js` has execute permission, if not, grant execute permission for it.

Comment: i already installed ANDROID_SDK, and i already added ANDROID_HOME to my path.. how can i added the JAVA_HOME?

Answer (score 1):

Ionic can't find your Java executable.
Try to make it accessible in your PATH:

```
export JAVA_HOME="your/path/to/jdk"
```

You can also try to put this line in `/etc/environment` and load it with:

```
source /etc/environment
```

as it is suggested in this post:
[How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)

Comment: i already tried with your method an the link post you are suggested.. but i still got the same error.. i also already set the permission to 777 on my "hooks" folder but still no luck

Comment: Not an Ubuntu expert, but maybe you can try to add the line in your `~/.bashrc` file and load it with `source ~/.bashrc`. What is the result of `echo $JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: i tried that, but still not working.. i get error messages "Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: No more ideas. In same situation, I had some luck with a complete reinstallation of java.

Comment: yeah i also ended up reinstalling the java.. i install through ubuntu software center the first time, now i install through ppa and it works now.

Comment: That's a good news. You can now have some fun with your android app.

Comment: Thanks for the response :)